# PDF from WKWebView gets cut off by navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, wkwebview

So I have a view controller that sets a WKWebView as its view and it loads a PDF from a website. But the navigationBar cuts off the top of the PDF, but it doesn't cut it off when a website is loaded. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
class WebView: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var urlString: String?
    var pdf: NSData?

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

        let url = URL(string: urlString ?? "https://www.cpp.edu")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        pdf = NSData(contentsOf: url)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))

    }

    @objc func shareTapped() {
        let view = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdf!], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]